# rabbitmq on heroku without credit card

Tags: heroku, rabbitmq, amqp

How to add rabbitmq (cloudAMQP) on Heroku without credit card details?
I am trying to configure cloudAMQP on Heroku from CLI .
For mongodb we can use mongoLab on Heroku without using credit card .But the same process does not work with cloudAMQP.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to cloudamqp.com directly and sign up for their free version. you will receive a connection string from them, when you sign up, and you can add it to your application configuration just like any other connection string.

I use cloudamqp.com directly, even with my heroku deployed projects. works quite well.

Comment: Thanks Derick,for the answer.